# How to handle special character in file path of a file in python

Tags: django, linux, python-2.7, operating-system

File_path :

```
What Is A_ V Can???and Can't???It Offer Us_ (ABC) (720p_30fps_H264-192kbit_AAC).mp4
```

File exists in server but my python code is unable to find file due to special characters.

```
(admin-venv)[ec2-user@ip-***-**-**-*** encoding]$ ls -l
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     root       95621513 Dec  5 13:14 What Is A_ V Can???and Can't???It Offer Us_ (ABC) (720p_30fps_H264-192kbit_AAC).mp4

(admin-venv)[ec2-user@ip-***-**-**-*** encoding]$ python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Sep  1 2016, 22:14:00)
[GCC 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-9)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> media_path = "What Is A_ V Can???and Can't???It Offer Us_ (ABC) (720p_30fps_H264-192kbit_AAC).mp4"
>>> import os
>>> print os.path.isfile(media_path)
False
>>> quit()
```

This giving me False.

Comment: which one is the "special character"?

Comment: there are many special characters in the file path like '?', '(', ''' etc

Comment: those are not a problem as far as I can tell, e.g. I have made a test `In [10]: os.path.isfile("?' _")
Out[10]: True`

Comment: could you also include the output of `ls -l` in the `/home/encoding` directory?

Comment: -rw-rw-r-- 1 encoding encoding   17291635 Nov 20 21:31 What Is A_ V Can?and Can't?It Offer Us_ (ABC) (720p_30fps_H264-192kbit_AAC).mp4

Comment: can you show us a bit more of your code? especially wha are you storing in the `file_path` because everything works fine for me.

Comment: import os
media_path = "/home/encoding/What Is A_ V Can?and Can't?It Offer Us_ (ABC) (720p_30fps_H264-192kbit_AAC).mp4"
print os.path.isfile(media_path)
False

Comment: don't add another comment, edit your question ;)

Comment: Added in code..

Comment: just like I said, there is nothing special about this filename, are you sure the absolute path is correct? what does `file "/home/encoding/What Is A_ V Can?and Can't?It Offer Us_ (ABC) (720p_30fps_H264-192kbit_AAC).mp4"` give you if you run it from console?

Comment: Now check. Attached all the terminal commands in in question.

Comment: what does `os.getcwd()` return?

Comment: '/home/encoding'

Comment: try to copy this file to a different file with a simpler name like `test.mp4` and check whether you still get the same result

Comment: Its giving True for test.mp4 case.

Comment: what operating system is it?

Comment: Amazon Linux AMI release 2016.03

Comment: Hard to tell,  I don't have any experience with AWS. Maybe there are certain limitations for that particular distribution